# Is Layout-land folder possible in all scenario's?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

I am new to Android Development, I'm creating an app with user registration and slot booking , for all the  devices and landscape portrait screens, kindly say perfect solutions to start the app with no issues.

Thanks.

Comment: Use `LinearLayout` as the `parent` layout of each screen and don't give any height in numbers. Use `wrap_content` or `fill_parent` for height of each widget.

Comment: For the slot booking and user registration , i am getting data from server online, will this effect the results in screen orientation ?

Comment: Don't talk like this. Screen Orientation never disturbs any web service. If you still getting any trouble then add `android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" ` in the activity tag of your `Manifest.xml`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should follow multi screen support as per android developer's documents.
Please follow below link for more info.

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html